# PHP - strpos doesn't work correctly for me?

Tags: php, json

So I am trying to search through JSON, using strpos for it, but it doesn't for me. I always get that "Items doesn't exist".

Here's the PHP

```
$getItems = file_get_contents('Items.json');
$decodeItems = json_decode($getItems,true);

//$output = ''.$decodeItems['items'][0]['name'].'';
$output = '';

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

    foreach($decodeItems['items'] as $data){
        if($chance = strpos($data, $searchq) !== FALSE){
            if($data['name'] == $chance){
                $name = $data['name'];
                $output .= "<div>".$name."</div>";
            }
        }
        else{
            $output = 'Items no';
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Example JSON

```
{"img":"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQh5hlcX0nvUOGsx8DdQBJjIAVHubSaIAlp1fb3YihQ-tWglYy0lfjjOr6fxjpQ7MFz373Fodyl0AXh-ENkMWinJ4eXcA8-ZFHUq1K_xum70ZO56oOJlyUgjHI5fA","name":"&#x2605 Bowie Knife","assetid":"6442574944","myprice":"155.36","condition":"","originalname":"\u2605 Bowie Knife","inspect":"steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198034643020A6442574944D2305887113904442996","special":"0","floatvalue":null,"bitskinsprice":"117.36"}
```

Comment: `strpos()` will never return true, so the check will always fail. I don't see anything related to JSON in he code (maybe $data is coming from JSON, but that's irrelvant, show $data instead of talking about JSON)

Comment: $data comes from foreach loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manual the return value of [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

So, I suggest you to change this part of your code:

```
if(strpos($data['name'], $searchq) === true)
```

to

```
if(strpos($data['name'], $searchq) !== FALSE)
```

> Updating my answer according to the comments below.

The JSON needs to follow the following notation in order for the code above to work:

```
{"items":[
   {
      "img":"img1",
      "name":"name1",
      "assetid":"1",
      "myprice":"155.36",
      "condition":"",
      "originalname":"name1 original",
      "inspect":"whatever",
      "special":"0",
      "floatvalue":null,
      "bitskinsprice":"117.36"
   },
   {
      "img":"img2",
      "name":"name2",
      "assetid":"2",
      "myprice":"175.11",
      "condition":"",
      "originalname":"name2 original",
      "inspect":"whatever2",
      "special":"0",
      "floatvalue":null,
      "bitskinsprice":"55.55"
   }
]};
```

> Updating my answer according to the comments below.

OK, I made some changes to your script to deal correctly with the JSON file.

```
$getItems = file_get_contents('Items.json');
$decodeItems = json_decode($getItems,true);

//$output = ''.$decodeItems['items'][0]['name'].'';
$output = '';

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

    foreach($decodeItems['items'] as $data){
       // this was *if($chance = strpos($data, $searchq) !== FALSE){*
       if(strpos($data['name'], $searchq) !== FALSE) {
          // here was another unneeded *if($data['name'] == $chance){*
          $name = $data['name'];
          $output .= "<div>".$name."</div>";
       }
    }
    
    if (empty($output)) {
      $output = 'Items no';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, Thanks. It works if I changed that and removed that ['name'] part, but it doesn't work the right way. If I type there item name, then it shows me all items, but I want it to show only those items which match the strpos. So If I type there Bowie, then it shows me items where is word Bowie in.

Comment: It seems like you didn't really decode your JSON items.
You should first do this 

    $decodeItems = json_decode($jsonString);

This shall fill $decodeItems with array of items where every one of them has its own *name* property, then your script continues in the same way above.

Comment: I am, I just posted "a bit" of code. I'll post everything.

Comment: Edited my first post :)

Comment: One thing, is the JSON string attached above is the string of one item? or is this the same JSON you are using? because that string doesn't contain any items inside, it seems to me as one item. when json_decode work on that then $decodeItems doesn't contain 'item' as key.

Comment: This json has 888 different items, I just posted one part of it here.

Comment: I added example to the answer of how the JSON string is supposed to be in order to make the code working as expected

Comment: Yeah, that's how my JSON looks like. I can also put my full JSON file to pastebin if needed :).

Comment: Yes, please it would be great to check it.

Comment: Thanks @JacobEvst, I made some changes to your script making it works according to your JSON file.
There was some code that you don't really need, and some other which I moved to another position

Comment: Dude, Thank you soo much! Where was the main problem? Because if I myself changed that line !== false, then it still didn't work for me.

Comment: There was set of issues, $chance was always carrying boolean value, then you were comparing it with $data['name'], this was never pass. And actually, you don't need to use that variable. Another thing, using if ... else to assign result to $output, may lead to have unneeded strings assigned to your $output variable.